# how to create enum values with es6 in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it possible to create enum values in JavaScript and assign them to integer values, similar to other languages. For example in C#, I declare an enum in the following way:

```
enum WeekDays
{
    Monday = 0,
    Tuesday =1,
    Wednesday = 2,
    Thursday = 3,
    Friday = 4,
    Saturday =5,
    Sunday = 6
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use object as an enum after freezing it like example below:

```
const WeekDays = Object.freeze({
  Monday: 0,
  Tuesday: 1,
  Wednesday: 2,
  Thursday: 3,
  Friday: 4,
  Saturday: 5,
  Sunday: 6
})
```

Comment: thanks, sorry i'm new to javascript, why do we use object.freeze and how can i put this in a file and use it in different parts of my application.when reading integer values from database, how can i convert it back to enum values?

Comment: make constants.js file in your project and put this into file like this

export const WeekDays

Answer (score 4):

You can create a simple object and export it via `module.exports`:

```
// days.js
module.exports = {
  Monday: 0,
  Tuesday: 1,
  Wednesday: 2,
  Thursday: 3,
  Friday: 4,
  Saturday: 5,
  Sunday: 6
}

// file-where-you-want-to-use.js
const DAYS = require('./days.js');
console.log(DAYS.Monday);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a plain old object:

```js
const WeekDays = {
    Monday: 0,
    Tuesday: 1,
    Wednesday: 2,
    Thursday: 3,
    Friday: 4,
    Saturday: 5,
    Sunday: 6
}

const day1 = WeekDays.Monday;
const day2 = WeekDays.Tuesday;

console.log(day1, day2, day1 === day2);
console.log(day1 === WeekDays.Monday, day2 === WeekDays.Tuesday);
```

Comment: thanks, I want to have this enum available through all my application. so if I put this in its own file, enum.js, how can use the weekdays in other files?

Comment: @arve you'll have to export the "enum", then you can import it in other files. See CommonJS: https://flaviocopes.com/commonjs/

Answer (score 0):

To add some sort of variables that you'd like to use:

```
// days.js
module.exports = {
  Monday: 0,
  Tuesday: 1,
  Wednesday: 2,
  Thursday: 3,
  Friday: 4,
  Saturday: 5,
  Sunday: 6
}

// file-where-you-want-to-use.js
const DAYS = require('./days.js');
const firstDayOfWeek = 'Monday';

console.log((DAYS)[firstDayOfWeek]);   // 0
```